# Compute the transformed joint density of $Y_1 = X_1, Y_2 = X_1 + X_2$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

The question is as follows:

Let $X_1, X_2$  be jointly distributed with joint density function given by $f(x_1, x_2) = 2e^{-x_1 - x_2}$ for $0<x_1<x_2<\infty$. Compute the joint density under the transformation $Y_1 = X_1, Y_2 = X_1 + X_2$.

I have computed the determinant of the Jacobian to be $1$, fairly certain this is correct. I have inverted the transformation to yield $x_1 = y_1, x_2 = y_2 - y_1$. However, if you substitute these into the original distribution $f(x_1, y_2)$ and multiply by the determinant of $J$, it simply reduces to $2e^{-y_1 - y_2 + y_1}$, or simply $2e^{- y_2}$. My concern is that, because one of the dependencies has now vanished, this is not a joint density function of $y_1, y_2$. Have I made some sort of error, or is this solution an acceptable one? The instructor for the course gave me very unhelpful response when I ask her this question, so I am not sure how to proceed. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is the support of the original joint density? Can $X_1,X_2$ take on any arbitrary positive values, or are they constrained to some other set?

Comment: The support is given by the inequality $0 < x_1 < x_2 < \infty$, 0 elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I approached it through the cdf

\begin{eqnarray*}
P\left(X_1 \geq y_1, X_2 \geq y_2 - X_1\right) &=& \int^{\infty}_{y_1} \int^{\infty}_{\max\left(y_2-x_1,x_1\right)} 2e^{-x_1}e^{-x_2}dx_1dx_2,\\
&=& \int^{\infty}_{y_1} 2e^{-x_1}e^{-\max\left(y_2-x_1,x_1\right)}dx_1.
\end{eqnarray*}

where I assume $y_2 \geq 2y_1$ due to the constraints on the support. The lower limit on the inner integral is due to the fact that you want $X_2 \geq y_2-X_1$ but also you must have $X_2 \geq X_1$. Note that $y_2 - x_1 \geq x_1$ if $x_1 \leq \frac{1}{2}y_2$, so we can split the integral into two parts,

$$\int^{\frac{1}{2}y_2}_{y_1} 2e^{-x_1}e^{-y_2}e^{x_1}dx_1 + \int^{\infty}_{\frac{1}{2}y_2}2e^{-2x_1}dx_1 = 2e^{-y_2}\left(\frac{1}{2}y_2-y_1\right)+e^{-y_2}.$$

Now you can differentiate to obtain the density. Indeed, the density works out to $2e^{-y_2}$, which does not explicitly depend on $y_1$ because the cdf is linear in that variable. However, $y_1$ may play a role in determining the support.

Comment: In what sense can $y_1$ play a role in determining the support? Thank you for your answer, very well thought out. I thought I was right about the the actual answer itself, but nice to see it from the more analytic approach.  Would the support of the new function not simply be $0 < y_1 < y_2 < \infty $?

Comment: If that is the support, then $y_1$ plays a role in it, right? So certain values of $y_2$ are invalid if they do not have the proper relationship with $y_1$.

Comment: Would a more correct expression of the support be $0 < y_1 < \infty \cap 0 < 2y_1 \leq y_2 < \infty$, this way the dependency is made clear.

Comment: I think it's just $\left\{\left(y_1,y_2\right)\,:\,0 < 2y_1 < y_2 < \infty\right\}$.

Comment: Okay yeah I see this is true, because $y_2$ is strictly greater. Is it still appropriate to call this function $f_{Y_1,Y_2}(y_1, y_2)$ even though the function does not explicitly take one of these arguments?

Comment: Sure -- the uniform density doesn't explicitly take the argument either. Also the strictness of the inequality doesn't really matter since this is a continuous random vector.